# remove space below the UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

how do I reduce the distance between the two items?
[image]

my code:

```
-(void)setupRightMenuButton{
    filtro = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-filtro-bar"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(buttonFilter)];
    busca = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-busca"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(moveToSearchView)];

    filtro.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    busca.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    filtro.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);
    busca.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(6, 0, -6, 0);

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:busca, filtro, nil] animated:YES];
}
```

My viewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setupLeftMenuButton];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0.49 green:0.075 blue:0.082 alpha:1]]; /*#7d1315*/
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(0, -60)
                                                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    [self setupRightMenuButton];
    self.title = @"Músicas";

}
```

I tried using the `filtro.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake (6, 0, -6, 0);` but it did not work

Comment: have you added any spacer between those two?

Comment: try to add buttons to nav bar instead of doing "setRightBarButtonItems"

Comment: have you tried changing the offset value in UIOffsetMake(0, -60) ? I am not sure why you give value as -60

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add buttons this way:

```
    UIButton *but1 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    UIView *but1View = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [but1View addSubview:but1];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:but1View];

    UIButton *but2 = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];
    UIView *but2View = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
    [but2View addSubview:but2];
    UIBarButtonItem *rightButton2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:but2View];

       self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=@[ rightButton,rightButton2];
```

you need to mention the postions of x and y for the both UIViews as where ou want your buttons on the nav bar.

Comment: you can add the image to buttons. I didnt mention that in the answer

Comment: necessary that the buttons remain the I am using. then the solution will not work

Comment: sorry that i didnt get what you said. What do you mean by buttons remain ?

Comment: You cant add buttons to uibarbutton, we can add only views to uibarbuttonitem. So we add add our buttons to view and we add view to the bar button item

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me. Try to create a button, then set the image to it and set the buttons frame.

```
let button: UIButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
let image = UIImage(named: "your_image")!
button.setImage(image , forState: UIControlState.Normal)
// optional -------------
button.addTarget(self, action: "your_function", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
// ------------
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.width, image.height)
let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Create as many barButtons as you want and then add them to navigationItem:

```
self.navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItems([barBtn1, barBtn2], animated: false)
```